# BindingList Leaking WeakReference

Tags: c#, memory

I am developing with C#, .net 3.5, Winforms. 
I am assigning some simple strings to a Grid, and refresh these Info quite frequently. 
I profile the Application using Ants.
The following little Code produces a memory leak, because For every String I assign an instance of WeakReference is hold in memory forever.

```
private void LoadData(string[] StatusInfo) {            
    _bindingList.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < StatusInfo.Length -1; i=i+2){
        _bindingList.Add(new Item(StatusInfo[i], StatusInfo[i+1])); 
    }
}

public class Item {
    public Item(string label, string value) {
        this.Label = label;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

If I comment these lines, no WeakReference instances are found by the profiler, if they are active, they easily sum up to 20000 instances of WeakReference per hour.

Comment: What type is your `_bindinglist` Are you waiting for it to go out of scope before checking for leakage?

Comment: Type is BindingList<Item>

Comment: No, the Grid and the  BindingList stays in scope for a long time, only the content is refreshed very often. But I found that these Instances of WeakReference stay in Memory even if I create a nwe BindingList every Time I assign new strings. Unfortunately, that did not help either.

Comment: @traveller where exactly are you using a WeakReference ? 
 _bindingList.Add(new Item(StatusInfo[i], StatusInfo[i+1]));
creates a regular reference if you created a WeakReference<Item>(...) 
that's a weak ref ..  is that what you meant to do ?

Comment: I do not explicitly use  WeakReference at all. When I domment out exactly  _bindingList.Add(new Item(StatusInfo[i], StatusInfo[i+1])); no wekreferences are produced...

Comment: Yes, I mean objects of type System.WeakReference

Comment: It's very unlikely the error is in the code you've presented. `BindingList` doesn't create `WeakReference`s on its own. It's much more likely that you're getting trouble from the component you're binding the list to - stuff like binding event handlers etc. Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: I am using Winforms, binding to Resco Smartgrid